# Display Count and distinct values for all columns in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table with 700 columns. I am trying to get a list of distinct values for each column and their count. I am using the below query to get the result for 1 column

```
Select distinct col1, count(*) from MyTable group by 1.
```

Result:

```
col1    count(*)
a       10
b       20
c       40
```

How can I get the result for all columns using a single query in the most optimal way?

Comment: 700 columns?   thats a wiiiide table, we've gotten our share of daily WTF questions today.   dynamic sql loop

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The basic query is:

```
select col001, count(*) from MyTable group by col001 union all
select col002, count(*) from MyTable group by col002 union all
. . . 
select col700, count(*) from MyTable group by col700 ;
```

Not pleasant, but that is basically the query you need to run.  SQL doesn't really do multiple independent aggregations more efficiently than doing them separately (even using `grouping sets`, in my experience).

You can construct the query.  One way is to run something like this:

```
select replace(replace('select [col], count(*) as cnt from [tab] group by [col] union all ',
                       '[tab]', table_name
                      ), '[col]', column_name
               )
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'mytable' and table_schema = ??;
```

You can then copy the generated SQL (removing the final `union all`) and run it.

Note:  That above is generic; the exact code might differ by database.

Answer (score 0):

A list with distinct values for each column is impossible. What if column A has 5 distinct values and column B has 7. What would your list look like?

The other question is easier, but as @Gordon Linoff states, takes 2 steps. Elaborating on his answer, for MS SQL:

```
select replace(replace(' count(distinct([col])) as [col],',
                       '[tab]', table_name
                      ), '[col]', column_name
               )
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'your_table';
```

Copy the results and paste them in a new query window between.

```
SELECT
[[results query 1]]
FROM your_table
```

Remember to delete the last ',' from query 1 results.

Answer (score 0):

Replace [table name] with the table you need counts for.

```
DECLARE @table varchar(100) = '[table name]'
DECLARE @i INT = 1, @cntOUT int, @SQL nvarchar(500) = ''
DECLARE @ParmDef nvarchar(500) = N'@cnt int OUTPUT'; 

SELECT column_id, name, 0 as record_count
INTO #T1  
FROM sys.all_columns c 
WHERE c.object_id = (SELECT object_id FROM sys.objects WHERE name = @table AND type = 'U')

WHILE @i <= (SELECT MAX(column_id) FROM #T1)
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT @cnt = COUNT(DISTINCT ' + name + ') FROM ' + @table + ';' 
    FROM #T1 WHERE column_id = @i;

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt = @SQL, @ParmDefinition = @ParmDef, @cnt = @cntOUT OUTPUT;
    UPDATE #T1 SET record_count = @cntOUT WHERE column_id = @i
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #T1
--DROP TABLE #T1
```